# Regular expression to support strings contacting special characters

Tags: regex

I have written down a regular expression to accept string like

`Name` 
`Name Surname`
and not to accept a sequence of spaces, and empty input.

Here is my regular expression:

```
regexp = "[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\s]*[A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9]"
```

How to update this, to create a regular expression accepting strings like:
`Name somestring.` (for example *"Name Jr."*)

and Strings like this:
`aaa-bbb` (for example *"Katty-Perry"*)

and Strings like this:
`aaa'bbb` (for example *"Drai'Lyn"*)

and strings like 
`aaa bbb`

and strings like 
`aaa`

at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would help
[\w\'-.]*

\w includes (a-bA-B0-9)
 and * matches 0 or more characters.

include characters such as ' , - 
Etc., to match further..

Answer (score 2):

I would try:

```
[a-z0-9]+([\s'-][a-z0-9]+)*.?
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/9KRChjJe9z)

Note that `x+` means 'one or more x", but you code `xx*`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you that regex

```
[\w \.-_']*
```

I think the best way is to specify by yourself the specific characters you want to accept (. or ' or ...)

Comment: Thank you. :) In this case the sequenc of spaces is accepted as a valid input

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this

\b(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[-' _][a-zA-Z0-9]+)?\.?)\b
```

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue.
The answer, that worked for me was
[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\s-\']*[A-Za-z0-9.]|[A-Za-z0-9]